# SQL: Compare parental hierarchies and exclude if duplicated

Tags: sql, duplicates, grouping, sql-server-2014

I want to exclude duplicates from my data, unless the duplicate is part of a new grouping /series.

```
CREATE TABLE #MYTEMPTABLE
(CHILD VARCHAR(2), PARENT VARCHAR(2),YEAR INT)
INSERT INTO #MYTEMPTABLE (CHILD, PARENT,YEAR)
VALUES 
('1B','1A',2014),
('1A','1A',2014),
('2B','2A',2014),
('2A','2A',2014),
('3A','3A',2014),
('3B','3A',2014),
 also would have ('3B','3B',2014)
('3C','3B',2014),
('4A','4A',2014),
('4B','4A',2014),
 and ('4B','4B',2014)
('4C','4B',2014)

CREATE TABLE #MYTEMPTABLE2
(CHILD VARCHAR(2), PARENT VARCHAR(2),YEAR INT)

INSERT INTO #MYTEMPTABLE2  (CHILD, PARENT,YEAR)
VALUES 
('1A','1A',2015),
('1C', '1A',2015),
('2B','2A',2015),
('2A', '2A',2015),
('3A','3A',2015),
('3B','3A',2015),
  ('3B','3B',2014)
('3C','3B',2015),
('4A','4A',2015),
('4B','4A',2015),
  ('4B','4B',2015),
('4D','4B',2015)
```

What I want now:
      1B, 1A
      1A, 1A
      2B, 2A
      2A, 2A
      3A, 3A
      3B, 3A
      3B, 3B
      3C, 3B
      4A ,4A
      4B, 4A
      4B, 4B
      4C, 4B
      1A, 1A
      1C, 1A
      4B, 4B
      4D, 4B

Comment: Your description doesn't make sense.  What is the difference between 2B,2A and 1A,1A?  It seems they should be treated the same way.

Comment: Apologies Gordon. In the first temporary table 1A is split into 1A and 1B. The next year 1A is split again so we get a new smaller 1A and a 1C. I need to know that this processing happened.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused, but what is the difference "in the data" between 2A, 2A in both which is a duplicate and 1A, 1A which is not? If there is no way to differentiate them, it won't be possible to write a query to

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I care about 1A, 1A the second time because it is part of the processing group which gave us 1C. In essence 1A will be smaller after that processing but this is all the data I have to go on and I want to keep a history of what happened.

Comment: So you want to compare two parent child hierarchies. If they are the same then exclude them. If they are different include them?

Comment: Yes sarin, that's it. Better explained than I did!

Comment: How many levels does this hierarchy exist on i.e. can a parent only ever have one level of children or can it have a child that has a child that has another child etc.... ?

Comment: The latter Sarin....

Comment: tough one this. might take a while unless the other gurus (Gordon and horse beat me to it)

Comment: Thank you all for help. It cheers me up that you think it is tough...

Comment: @OzzieChica please can you look at the new examples and update your question with the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query as:

```
--Step2: Get all data from first Table
SELECT PARENT,CHILD
FROM #MYTEMPTABLE
UNION ALL -- to allow valid duplicates
SELECT PARENT,CHILD
FROM #MYTEMPTABLE2 
WHERE PARENT IN (
-- Step1:Get parents which have a new Seq in second table
SELECT PARENT
FROM #MYTEMPTABLE2 T
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM #MYTEMPTABLE T1 
WHERE T.PARENT = T1.PARENT AND T.CHILD = T1.CHILD 
AND T.YEAR <> T1.YEAR)
)
```

Comment: I created a 3 level hierarchy 4A, B, C in table MyTempTable and then 4A, B, D in MyTempTable2 and expected to see 4A and 4B twice but only saw it once. Just checking with OP that this is their intention.

Comment: Thanks again Sarin, I would want to see 4A and 4B twice

Comment: Thanks a lot Deepshikha. With that query on the updated example I get 3B,3B and 3B, 3C twice. But if I exclude the year I do not, this gives me what I want. I think this is it, but need to do more testing!

Comment: Sorry to be difficult, but I don't think this works if there is more than a two level hierarchy. Look at the result for the newly added 3/4 Series rows.

Answer (score 0):

This was a tough one. I'm not 100% certain it is right but probably needs a university degree mathematician and sql guru in one to do this. It seems to show correctly based on your request. I have simplified and explained the query below:

[See SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1990)

```
With MYTEMPTABLEHierarchy AS (
      Explode the entire Hierarchy for #MYTEMPTABLE. i.e. work out which parent and child relationship is on which hierarchical level
    ),

MYTEMPTABLEHierarchy2 AS (
      Explode the entire Hierarchy for #MYTEMPTABLE2. i.e. work out which parent and child relationship is on which hierarchical level
    ),

EqualHierarchy AS (
      Take the rows that are the same in both hierarchies.
    ),

DifferentHierarchy AS (
      Take the rows that are different in both hierarchies.
    ),

DuplicateAncestorHierarchy AS (
    Use the parent rows that have a different hierarchy and find all of their parents which become the duplicates.
)
Select * from EqualHierarchy
UNION ALL
Select * from DifferentHierarchy
UNION ALL
Select * from DuplicateAncestorHierarchy
Order by HLevel, PARENT, CHILD
```

Comment: Sarin, thank you very much for this. I will test and come back.